# Accuracy of advanced parametric methods compared to kNN method

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

If kNN doesn't perform well for classification on a dataset, is there any hope for parametric methods to perform better? Kernel-based methods, SVM, random forests, and neural networks. Could any of these outperform kNN method?

Comment: Why do you call kNN nonparametric?

Answer (score 7):

The "no free lunch" theorems (Wolpert) suggest there are no a-priori distinctions between classifiers; essentially whether one classifier performs better than another depends on the nature of the dataset.  Note also for kNN a lot depends on what distance metric you use and how you choose a good value for k.  It is not unlikely that a well-tuned kNN classifier will out-perform a badly tuned SVM.  At the end of the day, there is only one way to know for sure if an SVM will out-perform a kNN on a particular dataset, which is to try it.

Comment: Well, in many practical situations you more-less know the environment, so optimizing selection of a classifier makes sense and do help.

Answer (score 4):

Hastie et al give a nice overview in [their book](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/), look into 2nd chapter. The short answer is yes. Otherwise why do you think these methods were developed and are still widely used?

Comment: Playing devil's advocate, one "otherwise" is that academics need to publish papers and get grants to be awarded tenure or to be promoted.  Also methods are often in fasion and get used more than their true value would suggests (until the next bandwagon comes along).  The majority of papers published in machine learning probably do not represent an improvement on standard methods, such as kNN or LDA or logistic regression.

Comment: @Dikran, yes you are right. But in the book I linked the overview is given in terms of practical use. Not everybody from academia publishes articles solely for purpose of promotion or tenure.

Comment: @mpiktas, not soley, no (I was just being cynical ;o)  It is important to realise though that the increment in performance introduced by most new methods over traditional techniques tend to be rather modest and often do not translate from evaluation on benchmark problems to real world applications.  ISTR David Hand wrote a good paper on this a few years ago, and it is well in accord with personal experience (e.g. linear SVMs and ridge regression tend to give very similar performance, with neither dominating the other - try writing a grant proposal to investigate ridge regression!).

Comment: @Dikran, "papers and grants" would also explain the scarcity of synthetic benchmarks, gensyntheticdata( N, dim, nfeature ... ) to evaluate methods -- or do you know of any at all ?

Comment: @Denis, no I've not used many synthetic benchmarks (apart from Ripley's SYNTH benchmark, but that is mostly useful for illustration rather than benchmarking).  I've often wondered about generating "realistic" synthetic benchmark datasets by training a classifier and a kernel density estimator on an real dataset and then using them to generate data in whatever quantities I want.  Haven't had time to investigate how well it works yet.

Comment: @Dikran, could you ask around who might use such ? There seem to me (amateur) to be quite different communities -- image processing, text ... with not much commonality. Plus, as you say above, that would kill papers with unknown data.